# Where to store Refresh token in PHP

Tags: php, jwt, authorization, refresh-token

I am trying to understand how to use access and refresh token.
I am not using OAuth, i just want to implement token system.

So far i understand next concept:

1. User is trying to log in with username and password.
2. Server process user credentials and if its correct, it generates JWT access token and refresh token ,sending it back.
3. If access token expires, app should generate new access token if refresh token is valid.

But i have following questions:

1. Do server send both access and refresh token to user after logging in, and if so, where should it be stored PHP (cookie, local storage, etc.) ? Also if its the case, should user send both tokens to server for each request?
2. How do user retrieve refresh token after closing browser, and later opening site again?
3. Should refresh token be stored in database linked to user, and do user need to provide refresh token, and then check if one in database is same to validate it?

Comment: I mean, you could do this yourself, but why? There are clearly many things you're unsure about. Why not just follow the OAuth standard, then you'll be compatible with OAuth clients already, which is good, and you also have a template for the behaviour you need to implement to be secure. Or just use an existing OAuth server implementation, then you don't have to re-invent the wheel (and risk doing it badly or insecurely).

Comment: Or are you trying to build a client in PHP to access a site which is implemented in the way you're describing. It wasn't clear if you're building the client, the server, or both in this scenario.

Comment: `Do i send both access and refresh token to user`...yes, otherwise how are they going to know what values to use?

Comment: `How do i retrieve refresh token when user closes browser, and later open site again`...not clear what you mean. What is `I` in this situation? The client, or the server? The client needs to store the refresh token somewhere securely so it can retrieve it when it needs it. The server needs to store it so it can validate any authentication attempts which use the refresh token.

Comment: `Should refresh token be stored in database linked to user`...if you like. Or any other secure storage you might have in mind. But obviously yes you need to associate it with a specific user when you store it.

Comment: `do user need to provide refresh token`...if they are wanting to obtain a new access token when their previous one has expired, then yes. But for regular authentication they would just provide their current access token.

Comment: I want to use tokens for my website, to secure only logged in users can access pages. I dont need complete OAuth service for logging in with Google etc, its for intern purposes only.

Comment: `should user send both tokens to server for each request`...no, what would be the point of that? They have two different purposes. One is for regular access, the other is just to request a new access token when the old one expires. Normally, refresh tokens eventually expire too and the user must provide their credentials again before they can re-authenticate.

Comment: `I dont need complete OAuth service for logging in`...well, you're halfway to re-creating the same sort of thing already. Yes you might not need to provide every conceivable flow, but you would still likely be able to get up and running a lot quicker by just re-using an existing component. And it's likely to be more secure and reliable if it's been developed by people who know what they're doing and have all the concepts (like the difference between access and refresh tokens) clear in their mind, and it's been tested and used a lot already.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use an existing library / module, or 3rd party login like MS Graph / Google / Apple etc. Then you can put your energy into adding some genuine value to your application with unique features, rather than trying to make a half-baked version of a process which is already standard and easily available at low/no cost. The only exception would be if you're doing this as an academic exercise to actually learn about the internals of authentication processes specifically.

Comment: I am using firebase/php-jwt library for generating tokens. If i understood you correctly, i should use already built library for login like Google instead of implementing my own logic? What are the names of those libraries?

Comment: Recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. But if you wanted to use Microsoft or Google logins, they both provide JavaScript and PHP libraries ready-made to integrate with their systems. More generally, you should be able to [find OAuth-compliant PHP libraries quite easily here](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+Oauth)

Comment: "I want to use tokens for my website" - are you under the belief that tokens are a more secure way to do things? If all you want to do is secure pages, the traditional and built-in PHP sessions should work with very minimal effort.

Comment: ^^^this is a good point. Unless you're designing an API for non-browser clients to access the endpoints, then you probably don't really need a token-based system.

Comment: I am trying to achieve, that users can be logged in after closing browser, and also implement that in android app after website, so i thought tokens are way to go.

Comment: Ah well yes, if you want to incorporate Android too then you would need to. But again it should be a lot easier if you follow a well-known standard like OAuth, because then you should find there are clients and server components readily available to help you implement it.